# Flutter responsive column

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flex3, singlechildscrollview, expanded

I have several containers which have a different content, eg. checkbox, text... They are placed in column which is inside SingleChildScrollView (scroll if the screen becomes too tiny).

I try to use extended flex and spacers to increase the size of my container to fill more space in the bigger screen, but SingleChildScrollView and expanded are incompatible.

If I remove my SingleChildScrollView I'm not sure if my list can always be displayed on a small height screen. I would like to set `minHeight` to keep content on some container and let others reduce.

Could you help me to find the most responsive solution?

Comment: Use 'Expanded' and 'Flexible' Widget for this.

Comment: I try this but how to handle minheight for container and overflow for small screen?

Comment: You can use [MediaQuery.of(context).size.height] this will  store its height in responsive way.

Comment: Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Telling us that information helps avoid duplicating effort and improves the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Expanded' and 'Flexible' Widget for this.

For example:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Item 1'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Item 2'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Item 3'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it give me an error :RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: just add the widget of SizedBox above column and give height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and let me know if it is working or not.